# Displaying Two Different Datasets on One Map

Tags: r, leaflet, gis, r-leaflet

I want to visualize two distinct datasets on a common map for comparison purposes (so they should have different Icons). So far, I've been using the following code, but it only allows me to display one dataset smoothly.
My datasets work like this on:
[image: ![![enter image description here]

When I run: dput(head(data_a))
dput(head(data_b)) the outputs are:

The output for data_a:

```
structure(list(Nr = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Name = c("MD95-2006", 
"IODP 302", "IODP 302", "IODP 302", "IODP 302", "IODP 302"), 
    Lat = c(57.083333, 87.89, 87.9036, 87.92118, 87.93333, 87.86658
    ), Long = c(-8.05, 137.65, 138.46065, 139.365501, 139.535, 
    136.17735), `18O` = c(0.69, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Info = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), Source = c("MD95-2006 planktic foraminifera ?13C and ?18O", 
    "https://www.ecord.org/expedition302/", "https://www.ecord.org/expedition302/", 
    "https://www.ecord.org/expedition302/", "https://www.ecord.org/expedition302/", 
    "https://www.ecord.org/expedition302/")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The output for data_b:

```
structure(list(Nr = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Name = c("Simstich", 
"Schiebel", "Schiebel", "Stangeew", "Stangeew", "Stangeew"), 
    Lat = c(75.003333, 62.50275, 67.225033, 56.2747, 53.4347, 
    52.874), Long = c(-7.313333, -13.99235, 2.920317, -48.6992, 
    -50.0673, -51.5128), `18O` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Info = c("data for different depths", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Source = c("https://doi.pangaea.de/10.1594/PANGAEA.82001?format=html#download", 
    "https://doi.pangaea.de/10.1594/PANGAEA.75647?format=html#download", 
    "https://doi.pangaea.de/10.1594/PANGAEA.75719", "https://doi.pangaea.de/10.1594/PANGAEA.706908", 
    "https://doi.pangaea.de/10.1594/PANGAEA.706908", "https://doi.pangaea.de/10.1594/PANGAEA.706908"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

This Is the code I do have right now and which works for one dataset :D

```
install.packages('readxl')
install.packages('leaflet')
library(leaflet)
library(readxl)

data_a <- read_excel('C:/Users/Location_map.xlsx', sheet = 'Core_Tops')
data_b <- read_excel('C:/Users/Location_map.xlsx', sheet = 'Tows')
dput(head(data_a))
dput(head(data_b))

lat_a <- data_a$Lat
lon_a <- data_a$Long
lat_b <- data_b$Lat
lon_b <- data_b$Long


map <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lng = lon_a, lat = lat_a) 

print(map)
```

The outcome (as I want but only for one dataset:)

[image]

When I use the code:

```
map <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lng = lon_a, lat = lat_a) %>%
```

I got following result:

[image]

the console output also displays no error:

```
> map <- leaflet() %>%
+   addTiles() %>%
+   addMarkers(lng = lon_a, lat = lat_a)%>%
+   addMarkers(lng = lon_b, lat = lat_b)
> print(map)
```

This question based on the question: [Errors in the metadata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77486602/errors-in-the-metadata)

(a stackoverlow member told me I should ask a new question ;)

Comment: In your final code snippet, should `#` be `%>%`?  Does adding `print(map)` to the same snippet (as in the previous snippet) give you waht you want?

Comment: When I do this I don´t see any Icons :e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is to assign different colors to the icons based on the datasets, you may need to merge the two datasets into one, create icons list to assign different colors based on condition and use addAwesomeMarkers instead of addMarkers . Here is how I would do it:

```
library(leaflet)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

    data_a <- structure(list(Nr = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Name = c("MD95-2006", 
"IODP 302", "IODP 302", "IODP 302", "IODP 302", "IODP 302"), 
    Lat = c(57.083333, 87.89, 87.9036, 87.92118, 87.93333, 87.86658
    ), Long = c(-8.05, 137.65, 138.46065, 139.365501, 139.535, 
    136.17735), `18O` = c(0.69, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Info = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), Source = c("MD95-2006 planktic foraminifera ?13C and ?18O", 
    "https://www.ecord.org/expedition302/", "https://www.ecord.org/expedition302/", 
    "https://www.ecord.org/expedition302/", "https://www.ecord.org/expedition302/", 
    "https://www.ecord.org/expedition302/")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


data_b <- structure(list(Nr = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Name = c("Simstich", 
"Schiebel", "Schiebel", "Stangeew", "Stangeew", "Stangeew"), 
    Lat = c(75.003333, 62.50275, 67.225033, 56.2747, 53.4347, 
    52.874), Long = c(-7.313333, -13.99235, 2.920317, -48.6992, 
    -50.0673, -51.5128), `18O` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Info = c("data for different depths", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Source = c("https://doi.pangaea.de/10.1594/PANGAEA.82001?format=html#download", 
    "https://doi.pangaea.de/10.1594/PANGAEA.75647?format=html#download", 
    "https://doi.pangaea.de/10.1594/PANGAEA.75719", "https://doi.pangaea.de/10.1594/PANGAEA.706908", 
    "https://doi.pangaea.de/10.1594/PANGAEA.706908", "https://doi.pangaea.de/10.1594/PANGAEA.706908"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

data <- bind_rows(list(data_a,data_b), .id="data_source")

icons <- awesomeIcons(
  icon = 'ios-close',
  iconColor = 'black',
  library = 'ion',
  markerColor = ifelse(data$data_source == 1, "green","red")
)

map <- leaflet(data) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addAwesomeMarkers(lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, icon = icons) 

print(map)
```

[image: result]

Comment: This looks good but I can´t see data_b

Comment: When I use your approce I got an emty map :e

Comment: I created data_a and data_b based on the two chunks of code in your post.

Comment: yea I see that the error is on my side can u have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77486602/errors-in-the-metadata there i post the data b may be you find the error

Comment: @Weiss, I am not sure but like others have mentioned, colorIcon may be issue that caused the error in your other question. There seems to be no reference to it in the R documentation. Typing ?colorIcon in the console gives me this result:
> ?colorIcon
No documentation for ‘colorIcon’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??colorIcon’